Issue with Entity Framework query not working when combined into one statement but works when split into two separate statements in .NET 8
// This query doesn't work as expected
List<Cloudadminauthlist> authOnlylist = _masterReadDb.Cloudadminauthlist
    .Where(x => x.Authcode != null && authcode.Contains(x.Authcode))
    .ToList();

// These two queries work fine
List<Cloudadminauthlist> authAlllist = _masterReadDb.Cloudadminauthlist.ToList();
List<Cloudadminauthlist> authlist = authAlllist
    .Where(x => x.Authcode != null && authcode.Contains(x.Authcode))
    .ToList();

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with my Entity Framework (EF) query in .NET 8. Specifically, I need to filter a list based on certain conditions involving a collection (authcode in this case). However, when I attempt to do this filtering in one query, it doesn't return the expected results. But surprisingly, when I split the query into two separate statements, it works perfectly fine.
As you can see, the logic of the queries is identical, but when I combine them into one, it doesn't return the expected results.
I've already confirmed that the authcode collection contains the correct values and that there are records in the Cloudadminauthlist table that should match the criteria.
Is there something specific to .NET 8 that might be affecting how EF handles queries when combined into one statement versus split into multiple statements? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can you show us an example of the different results of the two?

it doesn't return the expected results (0 results). When split into two queries, it returns 15 results as expected.

It does matter, a lot. EF has no problem and the second snippet isn't using EF. It loads the entire table in memory and uses LINQ-to-Objects. If the queries return different results, it's because C# and SQL behave differently.

First of all, there's no need at all for  x.Authcode != null. EF translates LINQ queries to SQL and SQL doesn't throw on null. Applying any operation to a NULL value returns NULL as well, which is treated as FALSE in WHERE. The clause authcode.Contains(x.Authcode) guarantees only non-null values will be loaded

Second, it's impossible to guess what authcode.Contains(x.Authcode) does from the question. Is authcode a list of strings or a string? If it's a list of strings, it gets translated to x.AuthCode in (@auth1, @auth2,...) where the parameters are the items in the list. If it's a string though, it gets translated to @authcode LIKE x.AuthCode. That's rather unusual possibly a bug. You're asking the database to find authcode patterns in the table that match a static @authcode value. You probably intended to use x.AuthCode.Contains (authcode)

String.Contains doesn't behave the same as SQL's pattern matching LIKE operator. If you wanted to find which stored short authcodes are included in the longer authcode parameter you'd have to write Where @authcode LIKE '%' +  x.authcode + '%'. That operation is very slow because it can't use indexes.

Thank you for your answer.    authcode is List  ,x.AuthCode.Contains (authcode)  not support
